# How do I redirect a mobile device with all query strings and hash in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I noticed in MVC4, there is a built in method called Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice. How do I use this to check if the request is a mobile then redirect to the controller and action of /mobile/index? I want to carry over any query strings and the location hash that was in the URL. Is there a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't want to redirect to a different controller and action for a mobile device since a mobile device should just require a different representation of the same model (you wouldn't want to duplicate your controller logic).  If you create a view with the `.Mobile.cshtml` extension (for C# Razor views), MVC4 will, by convention, use this view for mobile devices.

E.g. if you have this view in your `Home` folder

```
Index.cshtml
```

by adding this view to your `Home` folder

```
Index.Mobile.cshtml
```

MVC4 will render `Index.Mobile.cshtml` on mobile devices and `Index.cshtml` on non mobile devices.

That said, there may be times when it is necessary to do something specific for mobile devices.  E.g. if you wanted a different `_Layout.cshtml` for mobile devices, you could place the following in your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file

```
@{
    if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```