# MVC4 ASP.NET Mobile contacts form redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to make my site mobile ready. I am doing it by creating a duplicate index page called Index.Phone. Its going well. Most things are detected properly apart from when I submit my contacts page using mobile. Once contacts form is submitted I am trying to redirect to a thank you page. I can do this with desktop without any problem. When I use a Mobile to do it it redirects to my EmailSent.cshtml (desktop page) and not my EmailSent.Phone.cshtml. I believe it is due to the redirect from the controller and not from the client which I believe would use global.asax that I have sorted out.

This is the HomeController action which does get called.

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel pContactModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            bool myBool = SendEmail(pContactModel);
            if (myBool == false)
            {
                TempData["emailSent"] = "false";
                return RedirectToAction("Contact");
            }
            else
            {                    
                    return RedirectToAction("EmailSent");  
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

This is my EmailSent.cshtml for desktop...

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "desktop";
```

}

This is my EmailSent.Phone.cshtml which I am trying to invoke with the above redirect.

```
   @{
Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.Phone.cshtml";
Page.Title = "mobile";
```

}

Thank you for any help you give me. I have omitted the body of both files to keep it simple.

Comment: Where are you checking if the client is a mobile device? You mention `global.asax`, what have you done in that?

Comment: @greg84 He is using displayModes in MVC.

Comment: I have registered the bundles and then manually setup the contextConditions like this...`var phone = new DefaultDisplayMode("Phone")
            {
                ContextCondition = ctx => ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent() != null && ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent().Contains("iPhone")
            };`

Comment: So generally when I make a view request if it is an IPhone then it will relay the correct view based on my global.asax contextCondition and then just omits the word phone from the url. When doing a RedirectRequest from within the controller I cannot seem to get it to follow the same procedure. This is what I am trying to achieve. I believe it is because I am making a server request and not a client request. Although I am no expert with MVC at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384226/how-do-i-redirect-a-mobile-device-with-all-query-strings-and-hash-in-mvc4 this might help you

Comment: What s the code for the EmailSent action?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is just make your css conditional based on the @screen size or you can go by the browser. You would have to somehow create a condition to check what type of browser you have in order to render a specific view, so I would try to check what type of device/browser I am working with through css

Comment: What if he wants to send different *HTML* to the browser? Can't do that with CSS!

Comment: @greg84 in that case he would need to add a controller to render a page for that device but even still you would have to check the device that's rendering the page.

Comment: I am only trying to display a thank you page which doesn't really need much in it other than a logo and a route home. So maybe just a generic page for all devices which is what I will do. Though I wanted to establish where I was going wrong with this. Cheers for all help. So the global.asax doesn't work for a controller response redirect? Is that the case?

Comment: I'm not to good working with global asax myself but I do know if you don't need to create a different page for each device you can check for screen size or device/browser in your css file and render that page accordingly. I would think that would take a lot less time

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this is the fix, but...

There is a bug in MVC 4 RC and RTM that caused a problem with the view caching engine. After around 15 minutes the `DefaultDisplayMode` would be ignored. Read more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/09/17/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-caching-bug-fixed.aspx

You need to make sure you install version 1.0.1 of this Nuget package to fix this bug: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes/1.0.1

You can do this using Package Manager Console and running:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes -Version 1.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially thats the problem solved. Thank you.

```
public ActionResult EmailSent() { return View(); }        

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel pContactModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {        
            bool myBool = SendEmail(pContactModel);
            if (myBool == false)
            {
                TempData["emailSent"] = "false";
                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) { return View("Index.Phone"); } 
                else { return RedirectToAction("Contact"); }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) { return View("EmailSent.Phone"); } 
                else { return RedirectToAction("EmailSent"); }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) { return View("Index.Phone"); }
        }

        return View();
    }
```